# read each float numbers from text file and skip the rest on C

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

I been struggling with understanding scanf and how it actually works. I have the following text file:

```
this    is  a   test    !
25.0    400.0   400.0   0.0     0.0
20.0    200.0  400.0    3.0 4.0
30.0    50  600.0   1 .0    2.0
50.0    400.0  200.0    1 .0    -2.0
40.0    700.0   700.0   -1 .0   -2.0
```

Basically, the code is supposed to read each line and assign them to an individual array ( array A get the float numbers from the first column, array B gets the floats from the second column, and so on). The only thing I have managed to understand is how to open the file for reading:

```
FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
```

but I can't figure out how to extract the doubles from lines 1, 2, 3, and 4. I used a conditional statement to skip over line 1 by the way. and I read the rest with the following:

```
while  (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
            {
                    if (count < 1)
                    {
                            //printf("%s", line);
                            count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            printf("%s", line);
                    }

            }
```

the lines are printing, but again... not sure how to extract each individual number. Help would be appreciated.

Edit: solution picked

Here is the code that I used on this test application. As mentioned in the answers, the text file had some typos that made it harder to scan for data and they need to be edited before running the code. Also, a declaration for "int i = 0" has to be added to work on the array.

```
while  (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
            {
                 if( 5 == sscanf(line, "%f%f%f%f%f", &A[i], &B[i], &C[i], &D[i], &E[i]) ) 
                 {
                     i++;
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     printf( "Parse failed\n" );

                 }

            }
```

Comment: Its amazing what an extra space in an input file can do to an otherwise sound approach :)

Comment: @ryyker It really is interesting. Are there implementations on C or other languages that can read text files on a more human-like fashion? I know ML has a nifty way to cut lists into pieces and adding them to a list with a single method call but I can't think of any others at them moment.

Comment: Just saw your question this morning, sorry for delay.  _Are there implementations on C or other languages..._. I assume you are referring to the ability to read something and to automatically recognize (and correct) a typo.  I am not aware if there is such a language that would have this as a native capability.  Currently, you just have to put bounds around acceptable input formats (i.e. no extra spaces, .csv, or space delimited, etc), and your code has to put bounds on what it will accept as input (i.e. check for NULL or empty strings, put bounds around acceptable numbers, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if( 5 == sscanf(line, "%f%f%f%f%f", &A[i], &B[i], &C[i], &D[i], &E[i]) ) {
    /* Do something with values */
} else {
    printf( "Parse failed\n" );
}
```

Where `i` is incremented for every valid data line.

Comment: Just like @ryyker mentioned, I had to edit the input file that was given to me. After that fix, the code above worked as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

use `strtok()` and `atof()` in a loop like this, it will give you an array of 5 x 10: (essentially 5 arrays each with space for up to 10 floats)

I picked up extra spaces in OP input file that *may have been part of the problem*?  I have removed extra spaces in input on lines 3 and 4, i.e. changed `1 .0` to `1.0`)  (And, as I look at the OP now, I do not see the extra spaces)  In any case, try this to read the file into an array:

```
25.0    400.0   400.0   0.0     0.0
20.0    200.0  400.0    3.0 4.0
30.0    50  600.0   1.0    2.0
50.0    400.0  200.0    1.0    -2.0
40.0    700.0   700.0   -1.0   -2.0

int main(void)
 {
    char *buf;
    char line[80];
    float A[5][10];//hard-coded to accommodate the input file, change as necessary. 
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("c:\\dev\\play\\test.txt", "r");
    int i=0, j=0;
    i = -1;
    j = -1;
    while(fgets (line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        j++;
        buf = strtok(line, " \n\t");
        while(buf)
        {
            i++;
            A[i][j] = atof(buf);
            buf = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        i=-1;
    }
    fclose(file);
 }
```

The output will be 5 arrays A[0] through A[4] each containing the contents of the 5 columns.

Comment: `strtok` is not thread-safe.  Better to use [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)

Comment: @paddy - `strtok_r()`, and `strtof()` are both useful when needed.  I write re-entrant code when its necessary.  It is just not necessary here when the main purpose is to demonstrate a concept, but thanks!.